# How to run bash 'tc' command within python?

Tags: python, linux, trafficshaping

I want to us traffic control of the Linux kernel with Python to simulate lost, corrupt and duplicate packages. I'm already able to configure this with the Linux Terminal, but I have to use python.

bash cmd works:

```
tc filter show dev eth1
```

python doesn't work:

```
>>> subprocess.call(["tc", "filter", "show", "dev", "eth1"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 470, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Thanks.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you have `tc` in the `PATH`?

Comment: Provide full path for `tc` ?

Comment: If it isn't, would it work in the Terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python subprocess doesn't know about your shell environment.  So provide absolute path to your command, something like:

```
subprocess.call(["/sbin/tc", "filter", "show", "dev", "eth1"])
```

find the exact location with command `which tc` in your shell.

Comment: That's simply not true. @checkThisOut may not have `/sbin` in the `PATH`. If it's there, the call will work without having to add the full path. It's advisable, though.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you should run the Python with the same user that has the privileges that are required to run the `tc` command.

Answer (score 0):

The basic way if you don't need any special control is to use `os.system()` to launch a command as if you were in your shell command line (no need to specify the full path if in your $PATH):

```
import os
os.system("tc filter show dev eth1")
```

This should work exactly as if you did in your cmd:

```
$ tc filter show dev eth1
```

Comment: This removes the error checking provided by `subprocess`.  What advantage does it offer?

Comment: I don't necessarily recommend the use of `os.system`. But in particular basic needs it could be more interesting than using a command with more parameters as `shell=True` to have benefits of context,...